# Python pd.read_excel - find duplicated rows in all Excel Sheets

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel report with a few million rows across three sheets. I try to use the below code to import the entire Excel file and all sheets and check for duplicated rows across all sheets and display all duplicated rows (except the first one).

If I run the code without sheet_name=None it works but it only analyses the first Sheet.

But when I add argument sheet_name=None hoping that all Sheets will be checked for duplicates - it doesn't work and I get an error.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Dup test.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
dups=df[df.duplicated()]
print(dups)
```

Does anyone know why it's happening? And how do I check for duplicated rows in every single sheet of my Excel file - please? Thank you.

This is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "\eu.ad.hertz.com\userdocs\irac920\Desktop\My Files\Python\4.py",
> line 4, in 
> dups=df[df.duplicated()] AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'duplicated'

Comment: "it doesn't work and I get an error" -- It would be much helpful if you'd have posted the error as part of your question.

Comment: @Justin Ezequiel Sure. Updated. Thank you.

Comment: It seems that your variable "df" is not a Pandas DataFrame but a Python dictionary instead.  It is likely that you have a Dataframe in there for each sheet of your Excel file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the attribute error because pandas returns a dictionary instead of a DataFrame when you specify sheet_name=None.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_excel('import-order.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
>>> type(df)
<class 'dict'>
>>> df.keys()
dict_keys(['header', 'detail', 'ps_orders', 'ps_order_detail', 'Sheet5', 'Sheet7'])
>>> type(df['header'])
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't mention that I am a complete beginner and only starting with Python. What I am trying to do is to see if I have any duplicated rows in my Excel file consisting of 3 sheets. I used below code to get the count of duplicates - but it only counts the duplicates in Sheet1 - any idea how to make Python count all duplicates in all 3 Sheets please? Can this be even done with pd.read_excel? Thank you.                                                                    
  import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Dup test.xlsx')
print(df.duplicated().sum())

Comment: See [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas-concat) to combine your datasets/sheets.